# Mono for Android HTML Source code with special characters

Tags: c#, android, html, xamarin.android

I'm using Mono for Android (C#) and WebClient DownloadString to get source code of a HTML website, that uses special characters (č,š,ž - charset=windows-1250). But when displaying the code, it shows � instead of the characters. Is there a way to show the correct characters?
I'm using MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `DownloadString`, .NET (and I suppose Mono, too) automatically assumes that downloaded data are encoded in UTF-8. In your case, that is not so, hence the � characters.

Instead of `DownloadString`, use `DownloadData` to download raw bytes and convert them to UTF-8:

```
byte[] win1250Bytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://whatever.com");
string utf8String = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250").GetString(win1250Bytes);
```

Comment: It works when using emulator, but when I try the app on an actual Android device, it returns this error: Encoding name 'windows-1250' not supported

Parameter name: name